# Is there a way to directly assign to object what we destructure?

Tags: javascript

I am sure what I am trying to accomplish can be done in a much simpler way. I unpack multiple fields and then I add the filtered object to an array.

```js
const filteredPersons = [];
const {state, name, age, weight, gpa, diet} = person;
filteredPersons.push({state, name, age, weight, gpa, diet});
```

When I try something like this, it does not work:

```js
const filteredPerson = {state, name, age, weight, gpa, diet} = person;
filteredPersons.push(filteredPerson);
```

This causes repetition and it looks really ugly.

Comment: Depends on what `person` is. You might want to `push(person)` or `push({...person})`? But if you want to take individual properties, it won't really get any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If there just couple of props you dont need to include from `person` means, you can use the following.

```
const filteredPersons = [];
const { unwanted1, unwanted2, ...restProps } = person;
filteredPersons.push(restProps);
```